# Can I install the rtl8812au driver on WSL Ubuntu?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, iwlwifi

Using `usbipd` I have made a wifi usb device accessible to WSL Ubuntu which does not have the appropriate driver.
I noticed the package `rtl8812au-dkms` could not get installed as is since WSL does not ship with a whole kernel so I wondered, is it still possible to have a WSL distribution that can use the rtl8812au driver?